# Best practice for a big array manipulation with values that never change and will be used in more than one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What would be the best and more efficient way in Rails if I want to use a hash of about 300-500 integers (but it will never be modified) and use it in more than one view in the application?

Should I save the data in the database?, create the hash in each action that is used? (this is what I do now, but the code looks ugly and inefficient), or is there another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put it in a constant? You said it will never change, so it fits either configuration or constant.
Using the cache has the downside that it can be dropped out of cache, triggering a reload, which seems quite useless in this case.
The overhead of having it always in memory is none, 500 integers are 4KB or something like that at most, you are safe.

You can write the hash manually or load a YAML file (or whatever) if you prefer, your choice.

My suggestion is create a file `app/models/whatever.rb` and:

```
module Whatever
  MY_HASH = {
    1 => 241
  }.freeze
end
```

This will be preloaded by rails on startup (in production) and kept in memory all the time.

You can access those valus in view with `Whatever::MY_HASH[1]`, or you can write a wrapper method like

```
module Whatever
  MY_HASH = {
    1 => 241
  }.freeze

  def self.get(id)
    MY_HASH.fetch(id)
  end
end
```

And use that `Whatever.get(1)`

Comment: From what I searched it seems the best option, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the data will never be changed, why not just calculate the values before hand and write them directly into the view?

Another option would be to put the values into a singleton and cache them there.

```
require 'singleton'

class MyHashValues
  include Singleton

  def initialize
    # 
    @results = calculation
  end

  def result_key_1
    @results[:result_key_1]
  end

  def calculation
    Hash.new
  end
end

MyHashValues.instance.result_key_1
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I didn't explain well, the hash values won't be calculated, It's just a hash that I want to load and use in the application (and the calculations are done on the fly using parameters that the user enters on a form), for example I want to use this hash `{1 => 30423, 2 => 423423, ......, 500 => 42340}`, this won't change ever, but in a view a user wants to know the cumulative value of the hash from the index 50 to 340, that's what my application do

Answer (score 0):

Cache it, it'll do exactly what you want and it's a standard Rails component.  If you're not caching yet, check out the [Rails docs on caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html).  If you use the memory store, your data will essentially be in RAM.

You will then be able to do this sort of thing

```
# The block contains the value to cache, if there's a miss 
# Setting the value is done initially and after the cache 
# expires or is cleared.

# put this in application controller and make it a helper method

def integer_hash
  cache.fetch('integer_hash') { ... } 
end
helper_method :integer_hash
```